# How to handle error message (0x80071ac5) when System Restore fails in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, restore, system-restore

The following error message appears:--

"System Restore did not complete successfully. Your computer's system files and settings were not changed."

"Details: System Restore failed while deleting the following fle/directory:

"Path: C:\Users\HRHfl\iCloud

"Drive\iCloud~is~workflow~my~workflows\desktop.ini

"An unspecified error occurred during System Restore. ((0x80071ac5)

Comment: This seems to be a common problem (bug?) while attempting a restore from cloud-based services.  With AWS US-East-1 being down yesterday, it could be related.  Might be best to re-attempt the restore during non-peak hours, and over a stable (eg, non-wireless, non-battery powered) connection; and exclude folders being used by the restore program itself.  Alternately, contact your backup vendor (iCloud?) to see if they can ship you a disk of your files.  It may cost extra, but it's super-handy and potentially faster restore process.